# An example problem to solve using 100 qubits?

Tags: electrons, quantum-spin, computational-physics, spinors, algorithms

Suppose we have in our possession 100 pairs of electrons.

Each electron **A1 - A100** is entangled with its respective twin **B1 - B100**. Each entangled electron pair has been set up to have opposite spins (UP = 1, DOWN = 0).

Is there a simple problem as an example that can be solved using these 200 electrons?

(Simple as in *not Shor's or Grover's algorithms*, but simple problem and calculation understandable with high school level mathematics)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one problem that can be solved using entangled qubits:

Alan wants to see a photograph. He knows that Bill is behind him looking over his shoulder. Alan does not want Bill to see the photo.

[image]

Alan places a sheet of entangled LCD film covering the photo. He placed the entangled twin sheet of LCD film behind him. A measurement of all the spin directs the film to be randomly transparent or opaque.

[image]

Alan can see the photo very easily through this 50% random access to the pixel information.

However, because the LCD behind Alan perfectly obscures exactly the same 50% openings that Alan can see through, Bill looking from behind Alan can get no information at all about the photo visible to Alan.

**An alternative use is as follows**:

Two siblings Luke and Leia have been separated from birth. At the time they were separated, their mother gave them 2 entangled LCD sheets as above.

The mother further tells each one of the siblings: "When you are ready, you can once and for all confirm that the other is your real twin, by putting the two LCD sheets together and activating them. Perfectly entangled sheets will be random yet 100% opaque, which is not reproducible by any other means."

Thoughts and suggestions?

Comment: I'm not entirely certain what an entangled LCD sheet is or how it's expected to actually *work*, but putting that aside for a moment - does this offer any advantages over using two ordinary polarizers with orthogonal orientations, or even Alan simply putting a completely opaque screen behind him?

Comment: @J.Murray Yes i guess the first example isn't as good as the second, because any matching complementary keys will work. Mechanism might be: inhomogeneous magnetic field directs electron up or down. A detector only on the up deflection location controls an electric transistor which directs appropriate current that switches transparent/opaque this particular pixel's lcd panel.